# How can I change the public path to something containing an underscore in Laravel Mix?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-elixir, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

In Laravel 5.4 Mix was introduced to compile assets and maintain the asset pipeline.  Mix defaults to your public directory being named `public`.  In many cases, including mine, my public directory is called something else.  In my case, it's `public_html`.

How can I change the public directory where assets are compiled to?

I have tried changing the paths within `webpack.min.js` to:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public_html/assets/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public_html/assets/css');
```

Unfortunately this compiles to:

```
- public
|- _html
|-- assets
|--- css
|--- js
|- fonts
```

In Laravel 5.3 and Elixir this was as simple as:

```
elixir.config.publicPath = 'public_html/assets';
```

I have checked Mix's config file, but can't see anything obvious here.

*Please note: this is Laravel Mix, the npm package, so it's nothing to do with amends in the `index.php` file.*

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is an undocumented (I believe) method called `setPublicPath`.  You can then omit the public path from the output.  `setPublicPath` plays nicely with underscores.

```
mix.setPublicPath('public_html/');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'assets/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'assets/css');
```

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 5.5 I've solved like this,

```
mix.setPublicPath('public_html/')
    .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'front/js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/custom.js', 'front/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'front/css')
   .styles('resources/assets/css/custom.css', 'public_html/front/css/custom.css');
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.8

```
mix.config.publicPath='public_html';
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public_html/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public_html'/css');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.4 you can us this code:

in **AppServiceProvider** :

```
public function register()
{

    $this->app->bind('path.public', function () {
        return base_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'public_html';
    });

}
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with Laravel Mix.  Mix is an NPM package (javascript), as stated in my question.